# Convert Set<Int> to varargs efficiently in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, set, typed-arrays

I want to convert a Set of ints into a varargs (array of strings) and vice-versa.

Is there a more efficient way (than the code below) to achieve that in kotlin?

```
// SET<INT> -> VARARGS
// intIds: Set<Int>
val stringIds = intIds.toTypedArray().map { i -> i.toString() }.toTypedArray()
//to get varargs, use *stringIds

// SET<STRING> -> SET<INT>
// val stringIds: Set<String>
val intIds = stringIds?.stream()?.map { i -> i.toInt() }?.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit simpler

```
val stringIds = intIds.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray()
//to get varargs, use *stringIds

// SET<STRING> -> SET<INT>
// val stringIds: Set<String>
val intIds2 = stringIds.map { it.toInt() }.toSet()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val stringIds = arrayOfNulls<String>(intIds.size)
intIds.forEachIndexed { idx, it -> stringIds[idx] = it.toString() }
stringIds as Array<String> // assert no null elements here
// ^^ or you can create your own `mapToArray` extension

val intIds = stringIds.mapTo(HashSet(), String::toInt)
```